# Distance of two normal distribution functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\Phi(u)$ be the standard normal distribution function. We want to consider the following expression $\|\Phi(u/\sigma_l)-\Phi(u)\|_{\infty}$, where $\sigma_l\xrightarrow{l\rightarrow\infty}1$. For convenience let's say $\sigma_l=1-\frac{1}{l}$.

Is it possible to approximate the expression above in the following form:
\begin{align*}\|\Phi(u/\sigma_l)-\Phi(u)\|_{\infty}\leq f(l)\end{align*} where $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}f(l)=0$?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G(t)=\Phi(u/t)$ and $g(u)=u\varphi(u)$ where $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ are the standard normal CDF and PDF, respectively.

Then $G'(t)=-u\varphi(u/t)/t^2=-g(u/t)/t$ hence $|G'(t)|\leqslant|g|_\infty/t$. The MVT yields $|G(t)-G(1)|\leqslant|t-1|\cdot|G'(s)|$ for some $s$ in $(1,t)$. If $t=1-1/\ell$, then $|t-1|=1/\ell$ and $s\gt t$ hence $|G'(s)|\leqslant|g|_\infty/(\ell-1)$. Since $|g|_\infty=\varphi(1)=1/\sqrt{2\pi\mathrm e}$, this yields, for every $\ell\gt1$,
$$
f(\ell)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\mathrm e}(\ell-1)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have by the mean value theorem
$$|\Psi(u/\sigma_l)-\Psi(u)|=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}\left|1-\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}2\left(\frac 1{\sigma_l^2}-1\right)\right)\right|\leqslant Ce^{-u^2/2}u^2\left|\frac 1{\sigma_l^2}-1\right|,$$
where $\Psi(\cdot)$ is a density of normal distribution.

Integrating, we get the wanted result.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get it. By $\Phi$ I denoted the distribution function i.e. $\Phi(u)=P(X\leq u)$ if $X\sim N(0,1)$ and not the density function. Maybe there was a misunderstanding. If it's easy to see I apologise for my comment.

Comment: With the same argument you used we would have: \begin{align}|\Phi(u/\sigma_l)-\Phi(u)|\leq u|1-\frac{1}{\sigma_l}|\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{2\pi}} |1-\frac{1}{\sigma_l}|,\end{align} where $\phi$ denotes the density function of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: The problem here is that the last term depends on $u\in\mathbb{R}$. How could we approximate the sup-Norm?

Comment: @stroem You're right, I didn't answer your question. I've edited.